# Иконка справа от текста в menuitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне поместить иконку справа от текста? Условно text [icon]

```
<MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DelCardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGridReestr, Path=ItemsSource}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Icon:PackIconMaterial Kind="Delete" Height="15" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Icon:PackIconMaterial>
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MenuItem унаследован от HeaderedItemsControl, у которого свойство Header имеет тип object - точно так же, как и у ContentControl свойство Content. Это означает, что Header может быть не только строкой, но и, например, FrameworkElement'ом. Или задаваться через binding и DataTemplate.
В данном случае проще всего будет сделать как-то так:

```
<MenuItem
  Command="{Binding DelCardCommand}"
  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DataGridReestr, Path=ItemsSource}">
  <MenuItem.Header>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Text="Menu item text" />
      <Image
        Margin="3,0,0,0"
        Source="Resources/MyIcon.png" />
    </StackPanel>
  </MenuItem.Header>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Ооо, спасибо большое! Всё получилось